# htaccess remove index.php except when request contains a certain word

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite ruleset that strips index.php from the url and remaps it and is working perfectly. However I cannot get the condition to ignore the rule if the string contains a certain word to work.

So basically I need a rewrite when the url IS http://domain.url/foo/bar but NOT when it's http://domain.url/shaz/foo/bar

```
# Remove 'index.php' from url
# 1) redirect the client from "/index.php/foo/bar" to "/foo/bar"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
# ignore rule if
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^shaz [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^shaz  [NC]
# end ignore
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]

# 2) internally map "/foo/bar" to "/index.php/foo/bar"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
# END
```

What can I do to make this work correctly?

Comment: RewriteConds are joined by an implicit AND, unless you explicitly specify otherwise.

Comment: So `/index.php/shaz/foo/bar` should stay unchanged?

Comment: @anubhava yes it should stay unchanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
# Remove 'index.php' from url
# 1) redirect the client from "/index.php/foo/bar" to "/foo/bar"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(?!shaz)(\S+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]

# 2) internally map "/foo/bar" to "/index.php/foo/bar"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
# END
```

`(?!shaz)` is negative lookahead that skips match if `shaz` comes after `/index.php/`

Comment: Awesome, that worked great. Thank you, was struggling for hours last night and couldn't get it to work.